# Stringify MongoDB result to a http response of NodeJs

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, mongodb

I want to send a query to my MongoDB at MongoHQ of an existing id. The result of this query needs to be send with the response to the user. If I log the result of this query I get the json response.
Now if I stringify the same result I get the following error:

> TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON

The code:

```
http.createServer(function(request, response) {
    var tweety = db.find({"tweetId":"1337"});
    console.log(tweety);
    response.end(JSON.stringify(tweety));
}).listen(3000);
```

The JSON I get from the console.log():

```
{ _mongooseOptions: {},
  mongooseCollection:
   { collection:
      { db: [Object],
        collectionName: 'posts',
        internalHint: null,
        opts: {},
        slaveOk: false,
        serializeFunctions: false,
        raw: false,
        pkFactory: [Object],
        serverCapabilities: undefined },
     opts: { bufferCommands: true, capped: false },
     name: 'posts',
     conn:
      { base: [Object],
        collections: [Object],
        models: [Object],
        replica: false,
        hosts: null,
        host: 'dogen.mongohq.com',
        port: 10004,
        user: 'x',
        pass: 'x',
        name: 'TwitterBitcoin',
        options: [Object],
        otherDbs: [],
        _readyState: 1,
        _closeCalled: false,
        _hasOpened: true,
        _listening: true,
        _events: {},
        db: [Object] },
     queue: [],
     buffer: false },
  model:
   { [Function: model]
     base:
      { connections: [Object],
        plugins: [],
        models: [Object],
        modelSchemas: [Object],
        options: [Object] },
     modelName: 'Post',
     model: [Function: model],
     db:
      { base: [Object],
        collections: [Object],
        models: [Object],
        replica: false,
        hosts: null,
        host: 'dogen.mongohq.com',
        port: 10004,
        user: 'x',
        pass: 'x',
        name: 'TwitterBitcoin',
        options: [Object],
        otherDbs: [],
        _readyState: 1,
        _closeCalled: false,
        _hasOpened: true,
        _listening: true,
        _events: {},
        db: [Object] },
     discriminators: undefined,
     schema:
      { paths: [Object],
        subpaths: {},
        virtuals: [Object],
        nested: {},
        inherits: {},
        callQueue: [],
        _indexes: [],
        methods: {},
        statics: {},
        tree: [Object],
        _requiredpaths: [],
        discriminatorMapping: undefined,
        _indexedpaths: undefined,
        options: [Object],
        _events: {} },
     options: undefined,
     collection:
      { collection: [Object],
        opts: [Object],
        name: 'posts',
        conn: [Object],
        queue: [],
        buffer: false } },
  op: 'find',
  options: {},
  _conditions: { tweetId: '527920990878433280' },
  _fields: undefined,
  _update: undefined,
  _path: undefined,
  _distinct: undefined,
  _collection:
   { collection:
      { collection: [Object],
        opts: [Object],
        name: 'posts',
        conn: [Object],
        queue: [],
        buffer: false } },
  _castError: null }
```

**How can I send the JSON result as response?**

Comment: https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/cycle.js

Comment: I'm getting similar error.  I wish there was an answer here.